# Datatable error in dummy app - column does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I have an app with an Engine. Inside of this app I created a dummy app for tests.
I add a new migration in `my_engine`.
Then I import this new migration in the dummy app running `rails my_engine:install:migrations` then 'rake db:migrate'.

So know both schema looks identical.

However when I run my test I get

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column my_table.new_field does not exist`

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just ran the migration in `development` environment, but not in the `test` environment (thus, not in the test table).

Do the same command with the `RAILS_ENV=test` prefix

Answer (score 1):

Try running `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate` to run migrations on your `test` environment.

Alternatively, if you are using rails 4.1+ then you can add `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` to your `rails_helper`

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade

> What this does is that rather than just raising when the test schema has
>   pending migrations, Rails will try to load the schema. An exception will
>   now only be raised if there are pending migrations afterwards the schema
>   has been loaded.
>
> There are a few caveates to be aware of when using this:
>
> Migrations still need to be run manually; although now this only has to be done in the 'development' environment
>   An exception will be raised If the schema has not been initialized. The exception will provide instructions stating rake db:migrate needs to be run.

So adding this will mean you only have to run `db:migrate` once; just in your `development`